# Missing steps while rotating stepper motor with gear 20:1 and driver tmc5160

Tags: stepper-motor, stepper-driver, microstepping

as per the title I'm using Nema23 stepper motor and 20:1 gear and tmc5126 stepper driver. 1) I'm providing 3amp of current to motor and 4096 of microstepping. 2) Motor was working on same configuration with RHINO 1101 external driver but not working with tmc5160.
Am I missing something.
Tried:- Without gear Motor working fine. No issue with motor.

Datasheet can be found [here](http://bholanath.in/certificates-files/helical-worm-geared-TDS/BH60SH86-4004HL-20(620kgcm).pdf)

Comment: Show is your schematic and describe the circumstances in a bit more detail. What mechanical load is applied to the motor/gear output and does it miss many steps all the time or just randomly over time?

Comment: there is no load applied to it. Just gear with lead screw in it. It miss the steps all the time. It's not even rotating just missing steps with small noise. MotorWithGearis(http://bholanath.in/certificates-files/helical-worm-geared-TDS/BH60SH86-4004HL-20(620kgcm).pdf)

Comment: So it is not rotating at all? Could you have connected the motor windings in the wrong order? It will make the motor just vibrate at best.

Comment: Motor is not rotating it sleeping it's steps. I've connected and double checked the wiring also. I want to understand. 1) How to find what is maximum steps/mm we can give to the motor? 2) Maximum frequency controller/driver can provide to rotate biggest motor? 3) Increasing motor current will increase in torque is there anything else by which we can increase the torque?

Comment: So I've tried 2x microstepping to 32x and also provided from 500 to 50,000 steps/mm sometimes it was just making small movement and with the noise from motor like slipping steps not moving forward. All of this while connected with 20:1 gear.

Comment: All of that information belongs in the question rather than buried in the comments. You need to include the motor speed in steps/s, not steps/mm. If there is acceleration then you need to specify the start speed and acceleration rate. Your title and post say "missing steps" which suggests that the motor is running but misses *some* steps. Your comments suggest that the motor doesn't turn at all. You should fix this too. Use `1. ` for numbered lists or use the button on the editor toolbar.